# CSS transition with multiple transform changes?

Tags: css

I have a picture that I want to scale to 150% and also move 30px down, with a transition. Only the scale seems to work, any help?

```
img {
    transition: transform 250ms;
}

img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by proceed? You mean precede, and come before the translation?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question

Comment: @Adjit As in only the scaling works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to combine your transform properties

```
transform: scale(1.5) translateY(30px);
```

Should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks :) Been trying to combine them, but I tried using commas.

Comment: Sure thing! This also applies to changing just one transform property - for example, if you wanted to do just a scale on hover and your translateY was on the default state, you'd still need to set both on the hover, even though the translateY wouldn't change.